# Custom assignment tag received too many positional arguments

Tags: django, django-templates

Im using django 1.7.8 and checking doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags. I have written a assignment tag to check permissions. Under `/templatetags/folder_perms.py`

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_folder_permission(context, folder):
    request = context['request']
    return folder.has_read_permission(request)
```

I use it in my template like so:

```
...
{% load folder_perms_tags %}
...
{% get_folder_permission 'object.folder' as curr_perm %}
{{ curr_perm }}
...
```

When I render my template I get an error

```
'get_folder_permission' received too many positional arguments
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow im so dumb, was loading the wrong template tags

just had to change

```
{% load folder_perms_tags %}
```

to

```
{% load folder_perms %}
```